# Why can not conntect to the IP provided by my WSL console when i trying to use static-server for testing on mobile

Tags: npm, ip, ip-address, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ipconfig

I am using `NODE` and `npm` `static-server` to display my `.html` files on the local network.

I have no problems when I use `Git Bash` to deploy `static-server`. I was able to access from my mobile device using the ip that I got with `ipconfig` (the option LAN adapter Wi-Fi).

The problem is when I try to do the same process but from my **WSL Terminal** (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

The IP obtained with the `ip address` command allows me to access it from my own computer, but I cannot access it from my mobile device.

In the Git Bash environment the command `ipconfig` shows me several IPs including the Wi-Fi LAN adapter, and using it I was able to connect effectively. But in the WSL environment I only get one IP, and it does not work to access from my mobile through the Wi-Fi network, I just can access to it from the computer.

Does the NODE version have something to do with it? or should i use a different command in the WSL environment to obtain Wi-Fi LAN adapter IP? In this case, which command? Thanks

[Commparative image Basch vs WSL and NODE version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m3e9.png)

Comment: It's likely not a node issue.  You should see the exact same behavior if you do the same thing with `python3 -m http.server 8080` (or any other port).  This is most likely the same issue seen in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1618337/1210833), with the same suggested workarounds I gave there.  If that works for you, please remember to upvote the question and answer there (and close this question).  If not, let me know in a reply comment here and we'll see if we can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDr01ds. It solve my doubt. Definitely it's a limitations on WSL. I am glad they are working to solve that.